# "Вокруг церкви быстро вырос обширный приход"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Существуют разные версии городской легенды,  согласно которой
>   считается, что слово *popolo* проиcходит от латинского *populus* – 
>   «тополь».

<...>

> И название храма «del popolo» – не имеет отношения ни  тополям, ни к
>   народу, ни к собранным с него средствам. В данном случае оно было
>   присвоено храму Девы Марии оттого, что **вокруг церкви быстро вырос
>   обширный приход и продолжал расти и расти на протяжении столетий**.

Comment: Сомнительно нахождение _прихода церкви_ "**вокруг** церкви", поскольку прихожане (в религиозной риторике) принадлежат церкви, составляют её.

Comment: Саша, благодарю! )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае оно было присвоено храму Девы Марии **оттого, что** вокруг церкви быстро **вырос (или *образовался*)  обширный приход** и продолжал расти и расти на протяжении столетий.

Прихо́д — церковный **район** населения, имеющий свой особый храм с причтом, совершающим священнодействия для прихожан.

А про район можно сказать, что он вырос.

Может быть, использовать союз ***из-за того, что***?

Может быть, запятую поставить, чтобы разделить предложение, или союз КОТОРЫЙ?

В данном случае оно было присвоено храму Девы Марии из-за того, что вокруг церкви быстро **вырос обширный приход,  и продолжал расти и расти** на протяжении столетий.

В данном случае оно было присвоено храму Девы Марии из-за того, что вокруг церкви быстро вырос обширный **приход,  который** продолжал расти и расти на протяжении столетий.

Comment: По-моему, вариант с  "из-за того" и "который" решает большинство проблем.

Comment: Повтор "вырос, расти"  надо бы убрать.

Answer (score 2):

«В этом случае второе название было дано храму Девы Марии оттого, что у него сразу образовался обширный приход, который и растёт на протяжении столетий».

«...ни к народу, ни к собранным им средствам».

Answer (score 1):

"Вырос и продолжал расти" — а благозвучие уже не в моде?

"Присвоено оттого, что продолжал расти на протяжении столетий" — присвоено недавно, по результатам роста на протяжении столетий?

"Собранные с народа" — можно так говорить?